# Check inequality of two inputs in Cypress

Tags: unit-testing, cypress

I have to check whether a variable is less than a constant value in Cypress. How can we achieve this?

e.g: check whether a given variable is less than 30.

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a few assumptions here, but, something like the following *should* work.

```js
// define constant
const maxValue = 30;
cy.get('foo') // get element with variable text
  .then(($el) => { // use the yielded element in a .then()
    // get the text of the element using JQuery's `.text()`
    // and compare the value using Chai's `lessThan`.
    expect($el.text()).to.be.lessThan(maxValue);
  });
```

References for inline comments:

[JQuery's text()](https://api.jquery.com/text/)

[Chai's lessThan (alias for below)](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_below)